# "request access" when viewing a gallery room button covers message content on mobile chat

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web

If I view a gallery room on mobile, and *don't* want to request access, but I do want to read the last message in the room... that's a bit hard to do. The banner telling me that I need to request access covers the content of the messages at the bottom of the page, and there's no way to dismiss it without requesting access.

[image: screenshot of banner covering message content]

This is scrolled all the way to the bottom.

This seems like a bug; I should be able to view the message content even without requesting access. Maybe that banner should be dismissable?

Comment: Last line now reads: *If you have not read the RO letter about the proposed strike, please take a moment to review it before the meeting starts, as it may answer some of your questions* so you're not missing much ;)